# Page change using Ajax, still save data entered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am writing a practice website using jQuery's ajax. 
Currently I have 3 buttons, each of which, when clicked, shows different contents with forms using ajax call. The contents are stored in different files. Let's say you enter "AAA" in the form in the content shown after clicking the first button. Then you click on the second button, which will replace the first content with the new second one. And you enter "BBB" in the form on there. What I want to achieve is, when you do this, I don't want the page to forget what you typed in the first page (or before you changed the page using ajax call), and at the end, you press SUBMIT button, which is common in all buttons' content. Then, I want the webpage to submit both "AAA" and "BBB" for more computation.

Is this ever possible? 
This is kind of like a pizza website. Assume that there are 2 tabs on the website, one for pizza dough option, and the other for topping option. Also assume the pagenation of the tabs happens using ajax by asynchronously displaying the contents. When you choose options in pizza dough tab, and you change the tab to select topping options. Then you finally place the order, which reflects customers' option for both dough and topping.

How could you possibly implement this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Do I need a database using SQL? Since this is a simple practice website, it does not have to remember the customer's options once you submit the form and they close the page.

Here is some portion of my code since I cannot write them all. I also omitted some unimportant parts.

php file1:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dough, .topping").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: /*URL is either dough.php or topping.php*/
                success: function(data){
                    $(".result").html(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<button class="dough">Dough</button>
<button class="topping">Toppings</button>
<div class="result"></div> <!--Here I want to show the content with ajax-->
```

php file2 (=dough.php) and file3(=topping.php): /*This is the form-containing files and both have the same structure */

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="POST">
    <!--Pizza's dough and topping photos, price and name etc-->
    <input type="text" name="******"> <!--This is the input form-->
</form>
```

In this case, I feel like I should have the final "submit" button outside the form tag because the submit button is common and should stay at the bottom of the page during the course of pagenation.

Comment: the Single line code talks much better than your explanation. come with code what ever you tried so far.

Comment: You can try [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (or sessionStorage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="POST">
    <!--Pizza's dough and topping photos, price and name etc-->
    <input type="text" class='myValue' name="******">
    <!-- this button is for saving the input entered above; for topping form give 'toppings' class-->  
    <input class='option-button pizza-dough' type='button' value='select'/>
</form>
```

Add event handler for the above form(s)

```
$('.result').on('click','.pizza-dough,.toppings',function(e){
   //using on() because forms are dynamically added
   var myValue = $(this).siblings('.myValue').val();
   if(this).hasClass('.pizza-dough') {
       localStorage.setItem('pizza-dough', myValue);//store the value in localStorage
   }else{
       localStorage.setItem('toppings', myValue);//store the value in localStorage
   }
});
```

Now, suppose you have following common submit button

```
<input type='button' value='submit' class='submit-values'/>
```

Add event handler for this button to submit the values

```
$('.submit-values').click(function(e){
   var dataToSend = {'pizza-dough':localStorage.getItem('pizza-dough'),'topppings':localStorage.getItem('toppings')};
   $.ajax({
            url: /*submit url*/,
            method: "POST",
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function(data){
                //handle success
            },
            error: function(data){
                 //handle error
            }
   });
});
```

Adding validation for localStorage values is left for you.
Read more about [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to choose what best suits you.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but can you explain something for me? (1)For localStorage.setItem's first parameter does not have a period in front of "pizza-dough" and "toppings". In jQuery, don't you need a period to show it is a class name? (2) Does your suggestion mean I use 2 different ajax functions? one for getting asynchronous data from the server for pizza topping menu and pizza dough menu, and the other for the program you wrote at the end of your post? I am a bit confused.

Comment: I apologize if my original post does not make sense, or is hard to understand, but my "contents" means pizza topping menu and dough menu. By pressing DOUGH button, I want to asynchronously retrieve data from a different file and same for TOPPING button. Both use ajax. The ajax function you wrote is a new one, and used solely for submission?  Thank you in advance for your help and time!

Comment: I forgot to add: (3) For the common submit button, should I have it inside <form> tag (and in this case, does that mean I write the submit button in both dough.php and topping.php?) or should I take it out of the <form> tag (in this case, I write the submit button in php1 file only)? I apologize for attacking you with a bunch of questions =/

Comment: (1) localStorage.setItem() parameter is actually a key which you can give any name its not jquery. I gave key name same as class name just for example prupose. Go through the link I gave in answer to understand more about it.

Comment: (2)Yes according to your question I assumed that after selecting in both tabs you wanted to submit the pizza-dough and toppings values together (3) putting it outside would be more semantically correct. Let me know if you have any other doubts

Comment: Thank you for your great help! Then for (3), I got a new question. In php2 file and php3 file (that is, dough.php and topping.php which contain only form tags)'s <form> attribute already has action="confirm.php" and method="post". Should I remove these attributes and just write these in the ajax function you gave, where it says url: and method: ?

Comment: Yes that should be fine

Comment: Thank you for a lot of help!! You are awesome!

Comment: Glad to help. Mark the answer as accepted if it helped you so that it could help others

Comment: Hi anu, I got stuck again and was wondering if you could give me some idea again. For this example above, I have only one input inside <form> tag. What if there is an input for each items shown on the page? For example, say there are 10 different toppings, and the customer can choose which one they want and the amount of those (like cheddar cheese, 100g). Initially, they are all 0's and I want to assume they are not selected. Whenever the value is not 0, I want the program to understand the customer wants that item, and the number given is the gram.

Comment: Using localStorage method, if I do it exhaustively, like store all items whether the customer wants them or not, and then check if the number is 0 or not, I think I could do it. But I feel like that it is waste of space and slows down the speed, and that only those forms with non zero value (that is, the customer wants that item) should be stored in localStorage. But I am not sure if it is possible

Comment: It is possible, you can iterate over the input elements and save only the non-zero item in the localStorage(in array objects maybe). You need to show the html for help. Maybe add a new question(add this answer as reference) or give me a link to some [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response! Okay, let me try something out, and I will probably build a new question if I cannot figure it out. Thank you again, and you helped me learn a lot!